# Looking to understand music lyrics from the song "How We Do" by The Game

Tags: expressions, lyrics

Just for curiosity I would like some clarification of this line of the old song of The Game "How We Do." I would like to know the exact words and the meaning of them.

In min. 1:24 to min. 1:26 I simply hear

> "give me six inches on the white air ones."

However, I looked up for the lyrics and I found

> "If a nigga steps on my white Air, Ones"

well I just want to know if I'm listening correctly or if I need to train my ear a little more. Below are the links for the video and for the lyrics.

Link to the video:
https://youtu.be/PH34kMOjmQk

Link to the lyrics:
http://www.metrolyrics.com/this-is-how-we-do-lyrics-50-cent.html

Side note.
As I previously mentioned this is just for curiosity and to check my listening so please don't judge nor leave negative comments just help out or skip it to the next thread.

Comment: The video link is to a censored version of the song where the lyrics have been changed - if you search for a version with "explicit lyrics" it should match the lyrics on the lyrics site.

Comment: But what it says in the censored one? I wonder if I'm listening correctly.

Comment: Here is the link to the other version and it says the same. They still censor some parts though. https://youtu.be/xix0TFHGZ9c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general theme of this section of the song is: "We have valuable assets which we like to display. We are also willing and capable of protecting them with physical force".

The original lyric is:

> Come get, some, pistol grip, pump
>
> If a nigga step on them white Air, Ones

"*Come get, some*" = I'm ready and not afraid of anyone.
"*Pistol grip, pump*" = the kind of gun he has.
"*If a nigga steps on my white Air Ones*" = If someone steps on my shoes. (relating to the previous sentence. ie. "I'll shoot someone if they step on my shoes").

Altered lyric:

> "Come get, some, ____ grip, ____
>
> "Gimmie six inches on them white, Air, Ones"

The first line is the same as above except some words have been blanked from the lyric track. 
In the second line the meaning has been altered slightly.

"*Gimmie six inches of space*" is a phrase (though not a very common one) which means that someone is too close to you and you would like them to step away (the phrase can also be used to mean that someone is pestering/harassing you without being physically very close, but that's not how it's used here). By saying "*On them white Air, Ones*", he's implying that his shoes are special and are themselves worthy of personal space (perhaps even that he isn't afraid of the other person being so close to him, but he fears for his shoes). Either way, his shoes are the priority here.

[Link to original song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tMEqJOK_eY&feature=youtu.be&t=54s)

Note: This answer is simply to help understanding. These lyrics should not be taken as an example of "correct" English. It is written in a particular style which is not commonly used (but adds greatly to the variety and creativity of the music). Some of the differences may be obvious, but others will not be. Be careful.

Comment: What a bummer! The video you linked is not available. ): However, your answer it's inpressive. Good job and thanks!

Comment: _"Air Ones"_ are almost certainly  Nike _Air Force Ones,_ a classic sneaker that was the first basketball shoe to incorporate the Nike air cushion, and has long been considered a status symbol in urban communities.  See the wikipedia article for more background on the shoe:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_1_(shoe)  Although the _Force_ is elided from the name here, there is no reason to have a comma between _Air_ and _Ones._

Comment: @Adam: Yes. I didn't explicitly state it in my answer but it's undoubtedly specific meaning. The commas are used above to reflect the cadence of the song.

Comment: @Niall Is there a reason you are preferring the comma between _Air_ and _Ones_?

Comment: @Adam, Sorry I just added this as an after-thought to my last comment. Commas are used in the answer (like in the question) to reflect the cadence of the song.

Comment: @Niall - might be worth noting that in your answer, to distinguish  from grammatical function.

Comment: @Adam thanks for describing what Air Force Ones are, that is good info.

Comment: @Adam - Good point, I added a general warning as I didn't think it made sense to pick only one aspect where the content isn't correct English.